# How to create a .urp for universal robots?

Tags: robotic-arm

The polyscope platform of Universal Robots saves programs as *.urp. They are very different to urscrips. 
Is there a way to create such files without polyscope?

Comment: if the .urp file is text based, then you could use a text editor to create the file

Comment: the .urp is not text. :( is a binary file.

Comment: try opening it with 7-zip .... it may be compressed